# How to download WordPress data in JSON format?

Tags: java, android, json, wordpress

I am creating an android app that gets its data from a WordPress site using its REST API. But so far due to lack of resources, I have not been able to work it out.

So for now I was thinking of just downloading the WordPress data in JSON, save it locally, and then use it to parse and fill the contents in my app. Is there a process or plugin that can help me download the WordPress articles in JSON format?

Comment: You could write a plugin for it. https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: @Kevin I have already used significant amount of time just to figure out how to get the WordPress data into android(with no success). So don't want to go this route of writing my own plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You could download articles in CSV format and convert it to JSON, there are online tools to do that. Or you can use a plugin for download it on JSON format : https://wordpress.org/plugins/hiweb-export-posts/

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution to retrieve Wordpress data in JSON is to use the REST APIs. Using the APIs, you will be able to retrieve posts, Categories, Tags, Comments, etc.. all in JSON format where you can parse it.

You can check the REST API reference at [REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/)

Answer (score 0):

The Wordpress REST API outputs JSON by default so you shouldn't need any plugins for this.

You don't say if you're using Java or Kotlin for your app, so I've created a working example in Java just to make it available to more users. I've tried to keep the code as simple as possible without the use of any third party libraries for networking and JSON-parsing.

Manifest file with permission.INTERNET needed for networking:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.example.wordpressfetchdata">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String WORDPRESS_SITE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/wordpress"; //Use http://10.0.2.2 to access Wordpress running on localhost from emulator on same PC
    private static final String WORDPRESS_REST_API_URL = WORDPRESS_SITE_URL + "/wp-json/wp/v2";
    private static final String WORDPRESS_REST_API_POSTS_URL = WORDPRESS_REST_API_URL + "/posts";
    private static final String NEW_LINE = "\n";

    private TextView contentView;
    private LoadWordpressPostsTask loadWordpressPostsTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contentView = findViewById(R.id.content);

        loadPostsFromWordpress();
    }

    private void loadPostsFromWordpress() {
        //Create a AsyncTask which will load data on a background thread
        loadWordpressPostsTask = new LoadWordpressPostsTask();
        loadWordpressPostsTask.setListener(new LoadWordpressPostsTask.LoadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadSuccess(List<WordpressPost> data) {
                showPosts(data);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadFailure(String errorMessage) {
                showLoadError(errorMessage);
            }
        });
        loadWordpressPostsTask.execute(WORDPRESS_REST_API_POSTS_URL);
    }

    private void showLoadError(String errorMessage) {
        if (contentView != null) {
            contentView.setText(errorMessage);
        }
    }

    private void showPosts(List<WordpressPost> posts) {
        if (contentView != null) {
            int numPosts = posts.size();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "Loaded %d posts from Wordpress", numPosts));
            stringBuilder.append(NEW_LINE);
            for (WordpressPost post : posts) {
                stringBuilder.append(NEW_LINE);
                stringBuilder.append("Title: ");
                stringBuilder.append(post.getTitle());
                stringBuilder.append(NEW_LINE);
                stringBuilder.append("Content: ");
                stringBuilder.append(post.getContent());
            }
            contentView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        //Remove listener and AsyncTask to avoid memory leak
        if (loadWordpressPostsTask != null) {
            loadWordpressPostsTask.setListener(null);
            loadWordpressPostsTask = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    private static class LoadWordpressPostsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, LoadWordpressPostsTask.LoadResult> {
        private LoadListener listener;

        interface LoadListener {
            void onLoadSuccess(List<WordpressPost> result);

            void onLoadFailure(String errorMessage);
        }

        void setListener(LoadListener listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        class LoadResult {
            private List<WordpressPost> posts;
            private String errorMessage;

            LoadResult(List<WordpressPost> posts) {
                this.posts = posts;
            }

            LoadResult(String errorMessage) {
                this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
            }

            boolean hasError() {
                return errorMessage != null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected LoadResult doInBackground(String... urls) {
            LoadResult result = null;
            if (!isCancelled() && urls != null && urls.length > 0) {
                String urlString = urls[0];
                try {
                    String jsonData = loadJsonDataFromWordpress(urlString);
                    Log.d(TAG, String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "Got data from %s : %s", urlString, jsonData));

                    if (!isCancelled()) {
                        List<WordpressPost> posts = parseJsonData(jsonData);
                        result = new LoadResult(posts);
                    }

                } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                    result = new LoadResult(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        private List<WordpressPost> parseJsonData(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
            List<WordpressPost> wordpressPosts = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray posts = new JSONArray(jsonData);
            for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                //For  response properties see: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#schema
                JSONObject postObject = posts.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONObject titleObject = postObject.getJSONObject("title");
                String title = titleObject.getString("rendered");

                JSONObject contentObject = postObject.getJSONObject("content");
                String content = contentObject.getString("rendered");

                WordpressPost wordpressPost = new WordpressPost(title, content);
                wordpressPosts.add(wordpressPost);
            }
            return wordpressPosts;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(LoadResult result) {
            if (!isCancelled() && listener != null) {
                if (result != null) {
                    if (result.hasError()) {
                        listener.onLoadFailure(result.errorMessage);
                    } else {
                        List<WordpressPost> posts = result.posts;
                        listener.onLoadSuccess(posts);
                    }
                } else {
                    listener.onLoadFailure("No result!");
                }
            }
        }

        private String loadJsonDataFromWordpress(String urlString) throws IOException {
            String jsonData = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null; //Change this to HttpsURLConnection when using HTTPS, which you should be using!
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.connect();
                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    throw new IOException("HTTP error code: " + responseCode);
                }
                try (InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream()) {
                    if (stream != null) {
                        Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {
                            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
                            String line;
                            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                                buffer.append(line);
                            }
                            jsonData = buffer.toString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return jsonData;
        }
    }
}
```

Replace **WORDPRESS_SITE_URL** with the URL to your Wordpress site.

A POJO-class to hold Wordpress post data:

```
public class WordpressPost {
    private final String title;
    private final String content;

    WordpressPost(String title, String content) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

MainActivity layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```